# Downloading attachments from OWA?

Tags: windows-xp, outlook-web-access

How can you download all attachments in an e-mail at once using Outlook Web Access?

Comment: If this is a regular task then indeed setting up Outlook itself might be easier. When using multiple instances of Outlook for the same account on different computers, then both will be kept synchronised.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do by default simply because the attachments are normal hyperlinks.

Your best bet is to install a download manager such as [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) and then right click and do "Download all Hyperlinks" or similar, Free Download Manager should be able to find all of them and allow you to download at once.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can't. The only solution would be to connect a desktop client.